# Play websockets: send to one client or many

Tags: playframework, websocket

I'm trying to lean the Play Framework, using Scala.

For small projects, my go-to framework is currently Tornado. I use it because of how easy it makes it to use websockets. Here's how I'd use a websocket handler in Tornado:

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  """
  Handles websocket connections.
  """
  CLIENTS = set()

  def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.CLIENTS.add(self)
    self.send_data() // Perform special "on open" action.
```

Then, for each received messages, I'd do this from the websocket class:

```
def some_action(self, message):
  do_things()
  self.write_message(response_data) # If needed.
```

If an even occurs for which I need to update all clients, I'd do this:

```
new_data = database_callback_that_affects_all_clients()
for client in SocketHandler.CLIENTS:
  try:
    client.write_message(new_data)
  except WebSocketClosedError: pass # You can't always be sure which ones are closed.
```

One case sends the data back to the socket that made the request, one case sends the data to all websockets. But I use the same socket for both cases.

With Play, how should I handle that distinction?

The examples from the Websocket documentation webpage show how to send a message back to the sender and the chat sample application shows how to use the `BroadcastHub.sink` object to send a message to everything. But what if you need to do both, depending on the case?

- Should you keep a `Set` of `ActorRef` objects, like in Tornado? That seems the least Play-way of doing things.
- Or should you use two websockets, one for for responding to messages individually and one to broadcast messages to all clients in one action?

If the proper solution is the second one, I'm guessing that play requires opening two websockets for that.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like I was trying to do this all the wrong way and this is what I needed the whole time:

[image]